# What is the name of the pin that holds a toilet seat-and-lid hinge together?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

The lid on my toilet seat slammed down one time too many (I found this site by searching for the answer to *that* problem, which I had kluged by putting a bungee cord around the tank to hold the lid up while cleaning the bowl) and sheared off the pin around which the seat and lid and bolt extensions rotate. It's a piece of opaque plastic (acrylic?) and probably costs about a dollar, so I don't want to buy a whole new seat & lid combo just to replace that piece.

I intend to use the brilliant solution I found on this site (rotating the hinges 180 degrees) to keep this from happening again, but in the meantime I'd rather not send the seat & lid combo to the landfill for lack of a tiny piece of plastic. Any suggestions welcome.

To clarify for the helpful souls who responded so far: I do not want to *replace* the hinges if I can *repair* them. 
I'm not sure what the stainless steel bolt and nut refer to. The piece whose name (and buying site!) I am looking for is a small cylinder of plastic/acrylic/manmade whatever. There are no bolts or washers or parts that stick out. Just a smooth cylinder. Sorry that I wasn't clearer :-(

Comment: Stainless steel bolt and lock nut. ?

Comment: Go with the stainless nut and bolt.. easily available, simple to fit and cheap...

Comment: They do make seats that do not slam shut ,  Have two myself work great.  You may be able to buy the hinges..Or you can get bolt  but that does not stop the slamming.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm going to the hardware store for nylon spacer.  I will need the length of the pin and the outside diameter.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).